# Application verifier install issue

Tags: windows-7, application-verifier

I installed application verifier for detecting heap corruption in my application in Visual Studio 2010. The OS it runs on is Windows 7. The problem that I have is very stupid: I can't start the application verifier. I read that it is installed in the programs menu (but I don't find the application verifier there), or that I just run the AppVerif.exe (which I can't find either). In my application verifier folder I just have the REDIST.txt, vrfauto.dll, vrfauto.h, and vrfauto.idl files and nothing else.
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it again, but the contents of the folder remained the same, and no trace of AppVerif.exe on my computer. At this point, I don't know what to do. My application is stuck, and I can't move on. Help me, please!

Comment: Heh had the same problem with the exception that running AppVerif.exe worked.

Answer (score 5):

You should find the Application Verifier executable here:

```
<YourWindowsFolder>\SysWOW64\appverif.exe (x86 version)
<YourWindowsFolder>\System32\appverif.exe (x64 version)
```

I have two Win7 x64 machines, both have the same version of AppVerifier installed (6.2.9200), but one of them has correct application links, another - doesn't (just like you've described). It probably depends on which .NET Framework version is installed in the system. AppVerifier is old, and its installer may be incompatible with newer framework versions.